# Any experience with easylogging++

Tags: logging, easylogging++

I was looking for a relatively simple logging option without dependencies and noticed easylogging++. It looked mature, good documented, usint tests.

Started using it but ran into some hard to find problems which are hard to debug.

I was wondering if anybody has used easylogging++ and if it has been reliable. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time spent on debugging I found the cause of the problem which is as often the case quite logical. The header only concept of the library is nice, but configuration with #define must of course be consistent for every location the header file is included. This was not the case after expanding the application :-) which resulted in very strange and hard to debug behaviour.